# Switch statement, unrecognized input

Tags: c++, switch-statement

I am working through 'Programming principles and practices' After coding currency conversion using if else, I am writing one using switch statements.

I have 5 currencies to convert, and 4 of them work perfectly and 1 (Euros, E) does not. I cannot see why, although i'm sure it is very simple.

here is my code;

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){

constexpr double yen_to_dollars = 0.0091;
constexpr double euro_to_dollars = 1.071;
constexpr double pound_to_dollars = 1.279;
constexpr double yuan_to_dollars = 0.1452;
constexpr double kroner_to_dollars =0.1174;

double amount = 1;
char currency = ' ';

   std::cout<<"Please enter an amount, followed by the type of currency you want to convert (Y, E, P, Z, K): \n";
   std::cin >> amount >> currency;


    switch(currency){

    case 'Y':

        std::cout << amount << " Yen = " << yen_to_dollars*amount << " dollars\n";

    break;

    case 'E':

        std::cout << amount << " Euros = " << euro_to_dollars*amount << " dollars\n";

    break;

    case 'P':

        std::cout << amount << " Pounds = " << pound_to_dollars*amount << " dollars\n";

    break;

    case 'Z':

        std::cout << amount << " Yuan = " << yuan_to_dollars*amount << " dollars\n";

    break;

    case 'K':

        std::cout << amount << " Krone = " << kroner_to_dollars*amount << " dollars\n";

    break;

    default:

        std::cout << "That currency is unrecognised\n";

    break;



    }


}
```

If there are any other suggestions to make my code better please tell me. Thanks

Comment: `case 'Z'` corresponds with "Yuan"?

Comment: for which currency, it is not working ?

Comment: one suggestion. Don't use floating point numbers. They are approximations and hence inaccurate. Making them unsuitable for monetary calculations.

Comment: @UndefinedBehaviour sorry corrected now, its the euros

Comment: What output do you get when you enter `E`

Comment: @Pinky I originally had YU for yuan, but you can't use a string for switch right?

Comment: @Sniper it goes to the default

Comment: Did you try printing out both values before entering the switch? To ensure they are what you expect?

Comment: @Ross_Barkley Your code is working fine. http://ideone.com/UJapNz

Comment: The code works. You might be using small `e` instead of capital `E`, also missing `return 0`

Comment: @UndefinedBehaviour strange, not what my compiler is outputting, mine goes straight to the default (using codeblocks)

Comment: Let me guess , you're typing something like `1.03E` .  (it would be good to update the question to include the exact input you are providing that gives the undesirable output)

Comment: Do you leave a space between the number and the letter? If not it is interpreting the E as part of the number.

Comment: @Ross_Barkley its working fine in codeblocks too. Please update your input too.

Comment: Strange enough must be an issue on my end with the compiler then, when you say update your input, what do you mean? thanks @UndefinedBehaviour

Comment: @Ross_Barkley Please provide input what you are giving on your side.

Comment: @UndefinedBehaviour I see, I was doing 100Y, 100E, 100P, 100Z, 100K

Comment: @Ross_Barkley Okay. Now you got the answer. :)

Comment: @PaulRooney Ah, now it works, I wasn't leaving a space between the number and letter. strange though because I wasn't leaving a space between any of the other currencies and they worked fine..

Comment: @Ross_Barkley only the `e` has a special meaning.